# Scraping data from oddsportal.com with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been trying to extract the data for each cell on a number from this [ajax website](https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga/betis-real-sociedad-ld9FDhEI#), the details for each cell only pop-up when a mouse point on the cell.

I have used Python selenium `webdriver` and phantomjs to load and extract the page_source but the data wasn't found. I used firebug to look for any .json file that the content may be loading from but found none.

Please take a look at the site and suggest how I can scrape the content from the hover-box displaced when pointing on each cell on the map.

P.S: I have done a lot for research both on stack overflow and several sites all to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data is out there for grabs, all you need to do is get a good look at what's going on behind the scenes. How? Use the `Developer Tool` and inspect the requests. You'll surely notice that are two that have what you need:

- the bookies request -> https://www.oddsportal.com/res/x/bookies-201014103652-1602877009.js
- the data request -> https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/1-1-ld9FDhEI-1-2-yje1c.dat?_=1603009421226

The first one uses current time in seconds, and the other one in milliseconds. You have to swap that each time you make a request.

The bookies request is a mapping of all bookies from the site. This is how I got the `1xBet` code, which is `417`. You can easily map that with the odds data, for example, to fetch all history bets for a given bookie and/or bookies. There are plenty of possibilities here.

The odds request is, well, all the data that you see in those tables.

Then, you need to do a bit of regex to grab the `JSON` data that comes back with those two requests.

Finally, you can start poking around the payload and get what you need. For example, let say you're after `1xBet` and the `X` column. So you'd expect something like this:

`1xBet - 2.61 3.5 2.88`

and the history for the `X` column (here with value `3.5` above) could look something like this:

```
2020-10-18 05:03:45 - 3.58
2020-10-18 04:29:41 - 3.54
2020-10-18 02:53:17 - 3.56
2020-10-17 22:25:56 - 3.58
2020-10-17 17:13:53 - 3.60
2020-10-17 13:03:37 - 3.64
2020-10-17 10:12:06 - 3.66
and so on...
```

So, putting this all together, here's what I've come up with:

```
import json
import re
import time
from datetime import datetime

import requests


headers = {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
    "referer": "https://www.oddsportal.com/",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.99 Safari/537.36"
}


def get_response(url: str) -> str:
    return requests.get(url, headers=headers).text


time_now_s = int(time.time())
time_now_ms = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

bookies_js = f"https://www.oddsportal.com/res/x/bookies-201014103652-{time_now_s}.js"
odds_data_js = f"https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/1-1-ld9FDhEI-1-2-yje1c.dat?_={time_now_ms}"

bookies = json.loads(re.findall(r'bookmakersData=({.*});var', get_response(bookies_js))[0])
odds_data = json.loads(re.findall(r"\.dat',\s({.*})", get_response(odds_data_js))[0])

bookie = bookies['417']['WebName']  # 417 is 1xBet's code
bookies_odds = odds_data['d']['oddsdata']['back']['E-1-2-0-0-0']['odds']['417']  # current odds for a bookie
odds_sorted = dict(sorted(bookies_odds.items())).values()  # sorted as on the website 1 - X - 2

print(f"{bookie} - {' '.join(str(i) for i in odds_sorted)}")


history_columns = {
    "1": "4ccecxv464x0xbcsm1",  # 1 column
    "2": "4ccecxv464x0xbcsm2",  # 2 column
    "X": "4ccecxv498x0x0",  # X column
}

# odds history for the X column for a given bookie
history_data = odds_data['d']['history']['back'][history_columns['X']]['417']
for item in history_data:
    value, _, timestamp = item
    print(f"{datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)} - {value}")
```

Outputs:

```
1xBet - 2.61 3.5 2.88
2020-10-18 05:03:45 - 3.58
2020-10-18 04:29:41 - 3.54
2020-10-18 02:53:17 - 3.56
2020-10-17 22:25:56 - 3.58
2020-10-17 17:13:53 - 3.60
2020-10-17 13:03:37 - 3.64
2020-10-17 10:12:06 - 3.66
2020-10-17 09:58:04 - 3.64
2020-10-17 08:38:52 - 3.62
2020-10-17 08:08:54 - 3.64
2020-10-17 07:44:47 - 3.62
2020-10-17 06:17:33 - 3.64
2020-10-17 06:07:36 - 3.62
2020-10-17 00:04:35 - 3.64
2020-10-16 23:54:39 - 3.62
2020-10-16 23:38:40 - 3.64
2020-10-16 18:54:48 - 3.62
2020-10-16 15:14:17 - 3.64
2020-10-16 13:27:06 - 3.66
2020-10-01 21:43:39 - 3.40
```

Which is what you see on the web page for `1xBet` for column `X` once you hoover over the value.

Tip: if you ever run into the `missing oddsdata key` problem, take a look a the Developer Tool and see if the endpoint has changed. See this:

[image]

Just grab the new endpoint `https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/postmatchscore/1-ld9FDhEI-yje1c.dat?_=` or better yet go for this part `yje1c` part only and swap it with the one in the code.

Comment: I still getting this error.

 bookies_odds = odds_data['d']['oddsdata']['back']['E-1-2-0-0-0']['odds']['417']  # current odds for a bookie
KeyError: 'oddsdata'

Comment: Need your support

Comment: They change the endpoint that's serving the data. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Is there any way to grab those endpoint links with python? I would like to scrape many pages. So copying and pasting manually those endpoint links are not an option.

Comment: @vivekpatel have you found a way ?

Comment: Yes. I have found a way.  I use updated the code from Baduker. You can see my code on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309734/how-to-collect-data-into-single-item-from-multiple-urls-with-scrapy-python   Let me know if you do not understand anything.

Comment: @baduker Could you explain a bit more detailed where you found the booking and request? I never used Inspector before and looking through all the JS files under Network, but dont find the document or URLs.