# How to collect data into single item from multiple urls with scrapy python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, callback, scrapy

In simpler term, I would like to grab the return value from the callback function until the for loop exhausted and the yield single item after that.

**What I am trying to do is following,**
I am creating new links, which represent click on tabs on https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/caf-champions-league/al-ahly-es-setif-GKW6I7T6/
such as

1. https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/caf-champions-league/al-ahly-es-setif-GKW6I7T6/?r=2#ah;2
2. https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/caf-champions-league/al-ahly-es-setif-GKW6I7T6/?r=2#over-under;2
   and so on.
   But they are basically data for the same match, so I am trying to collect bet info into one single time.

Basically, I am using a for loop with dict to create a new link and yielding the request with callback function.

```py
class CountryLinksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'country_links'
    allowed_domains = ['oddsportal.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/caf-champions-league/es-setif-al-ahly-AsWAHRrD/']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.create_all_tabs_links_from_url)

    def create_all_tabs_links_from_url(self, response):
        current_url = response.request.url
        _other_useful_scrape_data_dict = OrderedDict(
            [('time', '19:00'), ('day', '14'), ('month', 'May'), ('year', '22'), ('Country', 'Africa'),
             ('League', 'CAF Champions'), ('Home', 'ES Setif'), ('Away', 'Al Ahly'), ('FT1', '2'), ('FT2', '2'),
             ('FT', 'FT'), ('1H H', '1'), ('1H A', '1'), ('1HHA', 'D'), ('2H H', '1'), ('2H A', 1), ('2HHA', 'D')])

        with requests.Session() as s:
            s.headers = {
                "accept": "*/*",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8",
                "referer": 'https://www.oddsportal.com',
                "user-agent": fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
            }
            r = s.get(current_url)
            version_id = re.search(r'"versionId":(\d+)', r.text).group(1)
            sport_id = re.search(r'"sportId":(\d+)', r.text).group(1)
            xeid = re.search(r'"id":"(.*?)"', r.text).group(1)

            xhash = urllib.parse.unquote(re.search(r'"xhash":"(.*?)"', r.text).group(1))

        unix = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        tabs_dict = {'#ah;2': ['5-2', 'AH full time', ['1', '2']], '#ah;3': ['5-3', 'AH 1st half', ['1', '2']],
                     '#ah;4': ['5-4', 'AH 2nd half', ['1', '2']], '#dnb;2': ['6-2', 'DNB full_time', ['1', '2']]}
        all_tabs_data = OrderedDict()
        all_tabs_data = all_tabs_data | _other_useful_scrape_data_dict

        for key, value in tabs_dict.items():
            api_url = f'https://fb.oddsportal.com/feed/match/{version_id}-{sport_id}-{xeid}-{value[0]}-{xhash}.dat?_={unix}'

            # goto each main tabs and get data from it and yield here
            single_tab_scrape_data = yield scrapy.http.Request(api_url,
                                                        callback=self.scrape_single_tab)
        # following i want to do (collect all the data from all tabs into single item)
        # all_tabs_data = all_tabs_data | single_tab_scrape_data # (as a dict)

    # yield all_tabs_data  # yield single dict with scrape data from all the tabs

    def scrape_single_tab(self, response):
        # sample scraped data from the response
        scrape_dict = OrderedDict([('AH full time -0.25 closing 2', 1.59), ('AH full time -0.25 closing 1', 2.3),
                                   ('AH full time -0.25 opening 2', 1.69), ('AH full time -0.25 opening 1', 2.12),
                                   ('AH full time -0.50 opening 1', ''), ('AH full time -0.50 opening 2', '')])

        yield scrape_dict
```

**What i have tried,**
first i tried simple returning the scrape item from the scrape_match_data fuction. but i could not find a way to grab the return value of callback function from the yield request.

I have tried using following libraries,
from inline_requests import inline_requests
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks

but i can not make it work. i feel like there must simpler way to append scraped item from different links into one item and yield it.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: This is not very clear to me (It may be to others but they have not posted an answer). `return_scraped_dict` is `None` because that is what the return value from a *yield expression` is. `all_page_data = all_page_data | _scrape_dict` must evaluate to an `OrderedDict` so I don't know why you have this. What are the keys to this scraped dictionary you would like to return? And I don't see a "callback" function as the term is commonly used. Why not have a function that simply iterates the `create_js_response_for_match_link` generator adding the values to a dictionary with the appropriate key?

Comment: Consider posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which might aid in your getting an answer.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comment. I have updated a minimal version of my code. Now it should work.  If I understand correctly your suggestion, I can not do it, because I have to make URL link with version_id, sport_id, xeid and xhash, and then I update tab value in the link at value[0] place.

Comment: It's not quite a minimal, reproducible example: It's missing imports and code that instantiates an instance of class `CountryLinksSpider` and invokes its methods. Also, `all_page_data = all_page_data | _scrape_dict` doesn't look right to me because you cannot do a bitwise or between two dictionaries. If you meant instead the `or` operator, it must evaluate as `_scrape_dict` because `all_page_data` is empty. By the way, since Python 3.7 a "regular` `dict` maintains insertion order.

Comment: Also, the presence of a `yield` statement within `create_js_response_for_match_link` makes it a *generator* function and invoking it as a function call does not execute its code but instead returns an iterator that when iterated executes the body code from the top the first time and following the previous executed `yield` statement. So this, too, does not appear to be correct unless `scrapy` knows how to handle generator function callbacks. Before you post a question looking for it to be modified, it should be something that already works. Does it as posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically in scrapy we have 2 approaches to transfer data between callback functions we are using to construct items from multiple requests:

**1. Request meta dictionary:**

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(
        url,
        callback=self.parse_details,
        meta = {'scraped_item_data': data})

def parse_details(self, response):
    scraped_data = response.meta.get('scraped_item_data') # <- not present in Your code
    ...
```

probably You missed to call `response.meta.get('_scrape_dict')` to access data scraped from previous callback function

**2. `cb_kwargs`** accessible for scrapy version 1.7 and newer:

```
def parse(self, response):
    ...
    yield Request(
        url,
        callback=self.parse_details,
        cb_kwargs={'scraped_item_data': data})

def parse_details(self, response, scraped_item_data):  # <- already accessible data from previous request
    ...
```

**3.Single Item from multiple.. responses with the same type.**
The easiest way to implement it is to assign data to class variable.
The code will look like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.tabs_data = []
    ...
    self.tabs_number = len(tabs) #  or len(list(tabs)) # <number of tabs
    for tab in tabs:
        yield Request(...

def parse_details(self, response)
    scraped_tab_data = ...
    self.tabs_data.append(scraped_tab_data)
    if len(self.tabs_data) == self.tabs_number: # when data from all tabs collected
        # compose one big item
        ...
        yield item
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, I need data from parse_details() method into parse method. Because for loop with tab_dict in my code is building new links with different tabs. But it is the same page. I am building links instead of clicking on tabs. So parse_details() (scrape_match_data()) method is just returning data from one single tab. so i want to collect all the data from all the tabs and yield it into a single item

Comment: I am renaming the methods name for better understanding

Comment: @vivekpatel answer updated

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked after doing few hacks. But thanks for pointing me on the right direction. I was hoping for a proper or let's say Scrapy way of doing this task. But it seems it does not exist.